# extract the most common (highest count) entry by group

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table:

```
ID       height
personA  182
personA  182
personA  182
personA  192
personA  172
personB  175
personB  175
```

I would like to extract the most commonly appearing height for this individual as I suspect 192 was a typo. So far, I have:

```
select ID, height, count(ID,height) as cnt
from tbl
group by ID, height
having max(cnt);
```

My desired output is:

```
ID       height
personA  182
personB  175
```

Comment: If you want the most occurred value, then your desired output should be 1-row:                 " personA 182". Or you want the most occurred two values.

Comment: most occurred value per ID. Sorry I didn't clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `mode` which is designed for your use case. Note that this won't handle ties

```
select id, mode(height) as height
from t
group by id;
```

Another alternative without using `analytic functions` that also handles ties

```
with cte as
(select id, height, count(*) as cnt 
from t
group by id, height)

select id, height
from cte
where (id, cnt) in (select id, max(cnt)
                    from cte
                    group by id)
```

If you were to implement the above using a `qualify` clause so cleverly used in Lukasz's answer, you could do

```
select id, height
from t
group by id, height
qualify max( count(*) ) over (partition by id) = count(*)
```

Comment: The cleanest solution as long there is no ties

Answer (score 2):

Using `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT ID, height
FROM tab
GROUP BY ID, height
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) = 1;
```

`RANK` used to handle ties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to rank the userids based on their count of height.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    ID
  , height
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(height) DESC) rn
FROM dbo.tbl
GROUP BY
  ID,
  height)

SELECT
    ID,
    height
FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```

Also you can use max() function to get the largest entry by ID..

```
select ID, max(height)
from tbl
group by ID
```

should work.

Comment: for reference, the nested select pattern can be avoid by using QUALIFY as per Lukasz's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the google analytic function. The analytic function will partition your table with your desired column. I have used row_number() function. You can also use the rank() function.
To know more about the analytic function : https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-row-number-function/

Code:

```
Select ID, height
From (SELECT *,
            row_number() over(partition by id, height order by height 
                              desc) as row_number
      FROM students)
Group By ID
having max(row_number)
```